# What type of math is needed to transform a speech wave to an equation

Tags: partial-derivative, wave-equation

Is it possible to find a mathematical equation for the graph of an mp3 recording of the word "Apple". What type of Math should I study to accomplish that, am guessing here is it the Wave equation and Partial deferential?

Comment: What is the graph of an mp3 recording? Note that mp3 is a format that uses a very sophisticated ecompression scheme ... But you may want to dig into *Fourier analysis*

Comment: There are many notations of a graph of a sound. Fourier analysis is one. the amplitude over time is another. Oscilloscopes might do something fun for you, too.

Comment: Math is very useful in the analysis of sound but not in the way you seem to expect. Recognizing speech is difficult, and there isn't going to be an equation that you can just write down that tells you what apple sounds like.

Comment: I understand that pattern recognition for speech is difficult, but what am trying to find is an equation of  "one unique"  graph that happened to be 
produced by a recording of a voice. The Fourier Analysis can it deduce an equation for this single graph, so when its plotted would recreate the same graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's mainly Fourier Analysis. It has to do with the acoustic fingerprint.

[Acoustic fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint)